# How to call an elgg module action via url

Tags: php, oauth, elgg

Im new to Elgg, My requirement is to create an Elgg plugin to import contact from Gmail,Yahoo and MSN.

I already successfully imported the contacts in Joomla. when I create an Elgg plugin and the Oauth call back url given like `invitefriends/gmailcallback` or even direct call like

```
mod/invitefriends/actions/gmailcallback.php
```

Its not working.

In first case it return form token missing I tried to add form token dynamically like below.

```
$ts = time();
    elgg_register_action('invitefriends/gmailcallback',
                        TRUE,
                        elgg_get_plugins_path() . 'invitefriends/actions/gmailcallback.php?__elgg_token='.generate_action_token($ts).'&__elgg_ts='.$ts);
```

But still same error.
so I  tried to access module file directly it works fine ,but the problem is I didn't get the `$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']` session variable are not getting, it set in default view and have proper value but unable to get that session in action file in direct call method.

Iam not sure its in Elgg standard, Please advice me to solve the problem

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use direct call. First thing: you're using deprecated action registration parameters - update your call. I assume you're writing to Elgg 1.8 or later.

You're additng action tokens in completely wrong way! They're necessary to prevent XSRF attacks, so need to pe added at URL generation. To elgg_register_action, you need to pass action file PATH, not URL. Use `elgg_add_action_tokens_to_url`and read through http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Actions#Security

You should get specific error telling you that, but you didn't mention it.

Comment: Yes Im using 1.8 , When I use elgg_add_action_tokens_to_url with how to write elgg_register_action(). Bcoz the url is returning from Google  oauth

Comment: If you need to hardcode oauth callback URL in external app, you need to do this through normal page, not an action. Every action will require tokens that are temporary in nature and bound to session of user that was logged in during call. You might need to write landing page for oauth as normal page (elgg_register_page_handler)

elgg_register action just registers file under specified system **path** as action with particular, made up, name. That has nothing to do with URL display and using action tokens at this point is simply incorrect - it won't work.

Comment: thanks for the details, I already integrated the system with action page not registered in start.php(loading Elgg engine to action page) Also in that action page nothing about security risk, just a call back from the Google oauth and those info is using under current logged in users session. is this method have any problem ?